# Make all entries before a zero to zeroes in a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I would like to convert all non zero values to zeros up to the last zero occurrence in a python dataframe column for each groups.

```
group | value | Result
 a    | 1     |  0
 a    | 2     |  0
 a    | 0     |  0
 a    | 1     |  0
 a    | 0     |  0
 a    | 1     |  1
 a    | 2     |  2
 b    | 1     |  0
 b    | 0     |  0
 b    | 2     |  2
```

One way I could think of achieving this is by reversing the `value` column and multiplying the elements above it up to that for each group, however I do not know how to do it in python dataframe.
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if all values to last `0` by compare values by `0`, swapped values by [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html) with [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) and last compare for not equal `0`, this mask is passed to [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
m = df['value'].eq(0).iloc[::-1].groupby(df['group']).cumsum().ne(0)
df['New'] = df['value'].mask(m, 0)
```

Similar solution with swapping back for original order:

```
df1 = df.iloc[::-1]
m = df1['value'].eq(0).groupby(df1['group']).cumsum().ne(0).iloc[::-1]
df['New'] = df['value'].mask(m, 0)

print (df)
  group  value  Result  New
0     a      1       0    0
1     a      2       0    0
2     a      0       0    0
3     a      1       0    0
4     a      0       0    0
5     a      1       1    1
6     a      2       2    2
7     b      1       0    0
8     b      0       0    0
9     b      2       2    2
```

Comment: both approach seem to give same results - what is the difference between the two approaches?

Comment: @user6386155 - My opinion - second is more strict, because there is explicitly change order by second `iloc`, so in oldier pandas version should working better second one.

Comment: @user6386155 - In first solution pandas implicitly change second order by origianl index (internally use `iloc[::-1]`)